# Format using jquery on div Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have 2 divs on my html

```
<div id='div0'>
   <table ..../>
</div>
<div id='div1'>
   <table id="table1" ..../>
</div>
```

div0 contains a master table
div1 contains detail table

I have a simple jquery

```
        $('#div1').find('#table1 td:nth-child(1)').each(function() {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).css('border-width', '4px');
                $(this).css('border-color','red');
        });
```

I am using telerik grid. The data is loaded on the page load event for the master and on rowclick event of the master loads the detail. Not putting all telerik code here as its not relevant.

Table in div1 is loaded when the user clicks a master record in div0's table
How can I fire the above jquery when my div1 has finished loading data?

Code for div1

```
                <div id="div1">
                    <asp:GridView ID="grdImages" PageSize="2" BorderWidth="0" PagerSettings-Visible="false" GridLines="None" CssClass="grid" AllowPaging="true" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false" CellSpacing="0" OnRowDataBound="grdImages_RowDataBound">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <table id="tabletest">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width: 15px">&nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;

                                                <asp:HyperLink CssClass="myclass" ID="imgBatchTif1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# getImageURL(Convert.ToString(Eval("ImageId1")),Convert.ToString(Eval("ImageFormat1")))%>' Height="150px" Width="190px" NavigateUrl='<%#"/ShowImage.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ImageId1")%>' Target="_blank" Visible="false"></asp:HyperLink>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                  </div>
```

Comment: It depends. How are you loading the data in the first place? There's not only one way to load data.

Comment: Also, `$(this).css({ 'border-width':'4px', 'border-color':'red'})`

Comment: I am using telerik grid. The data is loaded on the page load event for the master and on rowclick event of the master loads the detail

Comment: I'm not asking for a _description_ of what your code does. I'm asking for your code :) How are you loading the table in div1?

Comment: Just posted code for div1

Comment: Oh, so you're not using jQuery with something like `$("#div1").load()`? This would have been so easy. Unfortunately I am totally illiterate in ASP.

Comment: No because data is fetched from database